# Check whether an HTTP Request is from an android mobile or not using servlet/jsp

Tags: java, android, servlets

I would like to ask how can I ensure if an HttpRequest is from an android mobile without passing variable, using java servlet?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `User-Agent` header. [Here's a list](http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/). I guess you can check whether it contains "Android" or not.

```
if (request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase().contains("android")) { .. }
```